# I can't get superscript, subscript and underline buttons to render in the styles part of the toolbar in the ckeditor

Tags: cakephp, ckeditor

I am the webmaster for a small publication that uses the ckeditor on our back end system to handle post formatting. It has worked great so far. We were using the view source option to manually add some html tags to content. It worked but then I noticed it was striping the tags once I reopened the post on the back end and clicked source. In my journey to figure out why, I found that the editor will stripe code that doesn't belong basically. I started digging and found the config.js file that resides in my installation. That is when I discovered the `config.removeButtons` option in the config. I noticed it is specifically removing the options I need...Underline, Subscript, Superscript. Is there something I am missing? It looks like something that should be included in the standard toolbar.

I tried to delete it and save the file and reload the web page the editor is being used on and nothing happens.

This is the data in my config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here.
// For complete reference see:
// http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

// The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];

// Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
// not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

// Set the most common block elements.
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

// Simplify the dialog windows.
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';

config.extraPlugins = 'gwuploadmanager';

config.height = 500;
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: When you removed the `removeButtons` line, did you confirm that what loaded in your browser didn't have that? Or could it have been cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Greg! Of course it was being cached. I am not sure what cache specifically it was being held in because I removed the story cache in tmp/models within cakephp as well as cleared the browser cache. But it worked!!